# How to calculate volume of a right circular cone's hyperbola segment?

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

**PROBLEM**
I am working on calculating volumes of geometric solids. All shapes have been pretty basic until now.  I am bewildered on how to attack the problem of calculating the volume of a slice of a right circle cone.
Visualizing: The cone sits on a circular base with the apex directly above. The axis of symmetry passes through the apex and the center of the circle oriented normal to the circle.  Now, when you pass a cutting plane parallel with the cone's axis of symmetry at a distance between the circle's center and the circle's perimeter, a segment is 'cleaved' off.  I am looking to determine the volume of that segment.
*Note: All cone dimensions are known.*

[image]

**RESEARCH**
I have looked at numerous math and analytical geometry websites.  The most information I can seem to find just about the equations of lines or basic formulas (volume, surface area, etc.) I have even dug up my ancient Calculus textbook (yes, an actual paper book) yet still cannot find an approach.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**
I suspect that the solution will use DOUBLE INTEGRALS in some fashion but I am not sure. Frankly, even if it does use double integrals, I have been away from this for so long that I will need an example for how to work out the problem.

I want to apply calculus to more of my work but do not fully have the confidence to do so.

Thank you for any assistance or direction to a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume the following:

$$\text{Height of cone } = h \\
\text{Radius of the cone at its base } = R \\
\text{Distance from the cone axis to the slicing plane } = d,\quad 0\leq d\leq R.$$

Each horizontal slice of the solid is a circular segment. These segments vary in size due to the change of radius as we move vertically up or down the cone. Let's suppose at any such height $z$ the circle has radius $r$ and the segment subtends an angle $\theta$ at the circle centre (see the picture at the link below). Then, simple trigonometry/geometry shows that

$$\cos\frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{d}{r}, \\
\text{and the thickness of these slices will be: } dz = \dfrac{h}{R}dr.$$

(Actually, $r$ decreases as $z$ increases but this is handled by flipping the limits of integration below on $r$: $d$ to $R$ instead of $R$ to $d$.)

The [area for the segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment#Area) is:

\begin{align}
A_s &= \dfrac{r^2}{2}\left(\theta - \sin\theta\right) \\
&= \dfrac{r^2}{2}\left(2\cos^{-1}\dfrac{d}{r} - \sin\left(2\cos^{-1}\dfrac{d}{r}\right)\right) \\
&= r^2\cos^{-1}\dfrac{d}{r} - d\sqrt{r^2-d^2} \\
& \qquad\text{using $\;\sin(2\alpha)=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\;$ and $\;\cos(\sin^{-1}(a/b))=\sqrt{b^2-a^2}/b$}.
\end{align}

Therefore the volume of a thin horizontal slice of thickness $dz\;$ is

\begin{align}
dV &= A_sdz \\
&= A_s\dfrac{h}{R}dr \\
&= \dfrac{h}{R}\left(r^2\cos^{-1}\dfrac{d}{r} - d\sqrt{r^2-d^2}\right)dr.
\end{align}

Therefore the required volume is:

\begin{align}
V &= \int_{r=d}^{R} \dfrac{h}{R}\left(r^2\cos^{-1}\dfrac{d}{r} - d\sqrt{r^2-d^2}\right)\;dr \\
&= \dfrac{h}{3R}\left[-2dr\sqrt{r^2-d^2} + d^3\ln\left(\sqrt{r^2-d^2}+r\right) + r^3\cos^{-1}\dfrac{d}{r} \right]_{r=d}^{R} \\
& \qquad\text{using Wolfram Alpha} \\
&= \dfrac{h}{3}\left[-2d\sqrt{R^2-d^2} + \dfrac{d^3}{R}\ln\left(\sqrt{R^2-d^2}+R\right) + R^2\cos^{-1}\dfrac{d}{R} - \dfrac{d^3}{R}\ln{d} \right]. \\
\end{align}

As a sanity check, setting $d=0$ gives $V=\pi R^2h/6,$ and setting $d=R$ gives $V=0,$ as expected.

Comment: Thank you my friend.  I am re-inspired by your excellent solution and explanation. Thank you again.
@user36790

Comment: @RikiTando Glad to help.

Comment: @Blue 
Also, thank you people for correcting the title of my questions. I had not thought of it as yelling as in my field all text is capitalized.  Thank you.

Comment: @ Mick A .. @jadsq seems to suggest following, but I have not checked it myself.
$$ = \dfrac{h}{3} \left(-2d\sqrt{R^2-d^2} + \dfrac{d^3}{R} \ln \dfrac{\sqrt {R^2-d^2 }+R }{d} + R^2\cos^{-1}\dfrac{d}{R} \right) $$

Comment: @Narasimham Thanks! I've made the change. jadsq was right.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry I don't have enougth reputation to comment on Mick A's answer but there is a small mistake in the last line of his answer (assuming the previous one is correct) :

$$
V=\dfrac{h}{3}\left[-2d\sqrt{R^2-d^2} + \mathbf{\dfrac{d^3}{R}}\ln\left(\sqrt{R^2-d^2}+R\right) + R^2\cos^{-1}\dfrac{d}{R} - \dfrac{d^3}{R}\ln{d} \right].
$$

Edit : to satisfy Irregular User , I'll add that the formula above is the correct **answer** to the question.

Comment: technically the above commentators are right, it's not a full answer but still sort of gives an answer. As a compromise, could you just edit your answer in the way that you add the derivation of your result perhaps starting from the actual volume integral?

Comment: Thanks for the edit jadsq - will give you a +1 in 53 minutes when I can vote again :)

Answer (score 0):

i found a [detailed derivation of generic formula](http://www.academia.edu/30605701/Volume_and_surface_area_of_a_right_circular_cone_cut_by_a_plane_parallel_to_its_symmetrical_axis_Analysis_of_cut_cone_with_a_hyperbolic_section_) to calculate volume of slice of cone of radius of base $r$ & normal height $h$ cut by a plane at distance $x$ from the symmetry axis.

> $$volume \ of\ slice=\frac{h}{3r}\left(r^3\cos^{-1}\left(\frac xr\right)-rx\sqrt{R^2-x^2}+x^3\ln\left(\frac{r+\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}{x}\right)\right)$$