# Calculating the volume of a corner cut from the base of a right circular cone

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

I'm trying to find the volume of some arbitrary [concrete tetrapod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrapod_(structure)) (the things they use to break waves on a beach) and I've broken the problem into a few parts. There's the 4 partial cones and the tetrahedron in the middle (both easy to find), but the thing I'm struggling with is the volume of the overlapping "corners" between the cones.

[Image of a tetrapod 3D model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj1bg.png)

[Image showing the "corners"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSKPd.png)

I've managed to find similar questions about [cutting a cone with a vertical plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660071/how-to-calculate-volume-of-a-right-circular-cones-hyperbola-segment) and [finding the volume of a cone using parabolic slices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795309/finding-the-volume-of-a-cone-by-integration-of-parabolic-conic-sections), but in this case I'm dealing with elliptical sections. My current thinking is to maybe use triple integrals in cylindrical coordinates or something, but I have no clue how to set that up.

To give some specifics: each partial cone in the [model I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl3bV.png) has an equal diameter and height of 1 with a side slope of 4 (so ~14 deg, but this angle was sort of arbitrary and can be changed a bit if that would make calculations easier). The angle between cones is acos(1/3) (~109.5 deg).

My 3D modelling program gives a total volume of 1.797 units^3 and the volume of a single corner as 0.009 units^3 (this is as accurate as I can get, I think), but ideally I'm looking to make some sort of formula to find volume for a given base diameter.